# ComboBox DataSource, strange behavior when items are of different types

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

The items of a combobox are based on a collection whose elements are of type `Dog`.

```
public class Dog {
    public String Name { set; get; }
    public String Breed { set; get; }
}
```

Usage:

```
public partial class MyForm: Form
{
    private ArrayList dogs = new ArrayList();
    public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dogs.Add(new Dog() { Name = "Boby", Breed = "Pinscher" });
        dogs.Add(new Dog() { Name = "Sid", Breed = "Labrador" });

        comboBox1.DataSource = dogs;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }
}
```

Now i want to add a null element, but not by creating a dummy, empty object of `Dog` type: sometimes it's not possible.
Since `DisplayMember` is a String representing the name of a property, "Name" in this case, I thought that a different class type with the very same property would work.
This would allow for a very neat solution like this: 1) define a null-object (should be a singleton, but for the sake of brevity I keep it basic here):

```
public class NullObject
{
    public String Name { get { return ""; } }
}
```

and then (2) I add it to the collection:

```
dogs.Add(new NullObject());
```

This DOESN'T work and what i get is a combo like this:
[image: combobox-example1]

If I move the NullObject to the beginning, doing so:

```
dogs.Add(new NullObject());
dogs.Add(new Dog() { Name = "Boby", Breed = "Pinscher" });
dogs.Add(new Dog() { Name = "Sid", Breed = "Labrador" });
```

I'll get:
[image: combobox-example2]

So it's as if WinForms caches the object type of the first element and then expect the following to be the same type, otherwise fallback on ToString() method (that BTW when feasible *may be* a solution).

Is this a bug or is it documented somewhere? Is there another way of implementing this null-object pattern that works in combination with ComboBox?

#### UPDATE 1:

`ValueMember` seems to behave as initially supposed, that is it looks for a property of the specified name even if object types are different along the DataSource collection.

Comment: Just my advice.. never use arraylist. Use List<>

Comment: List<> would not allow objects of different types, that was needed here. Otherwise I should delcare an interface and implementi it both in Dog class and NullObject. Quite cumbersome for such a small task.

Comment: What would be the use of a *null* element when the array/list is used to provide elements to a ComboBox collection? Is this a dummy example? Wouldn't a Horse, I mean, a Dog with no name do the same thing?

Comment: Of course it would but this is just an example. In the real world, Dog might be a class created by a provider or so, or may have constraints that don't allow empty Name.

Comment: Get rid of the `DisplayMember` line, and override `ToString()` for your classes.  Now you can have disparate types in your ArrayList and each will display according to its overridden `ToString()`.  **I do not recommend this approach, however.**

Comment: IMO, it's not clear what kind of problem you're trying to solve (or if you're trying to create one :). Do you want to 1) Force the insertion of a null element for some reason. 2) Have a method that doesn't care if you receive null elements from an undefied source and put everything inside a ComboBox no matter what 3) Create a null element because you probably will need to supply a null element when a unspecified source requires one. No idea why this element would find its place inside a ComboBox. Maybe the dummy example here is too dummy to explain what is going on.

Comment: 1) It's not hard to imagine cases in which null is a valid option. 2) when you have a list of cars, null is not a particular car: this is just a trick because we don't have better solutions, that is what i'm looking for here. 3) What is an "unspecified source"? Go back to point one. There is nothing unspecified or weird. Just a way of handling the legitimate case in which a value is not provided. This is a  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern. Infact `dogs.Add(null);` would be *the* solution but it breaks the DisplayMember because WinForms tries to call  on null reference.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I've already tested that solution; you could also leave DisplayMember andoverride only the `ToString()` of `NullObject`, given that it works as a fallback. But this works only if `NullObject` isn't the first element and that makes it a bit tricky. On the other way, if `Dog` is a business logic object, `ToString()` may be needed for other uses. The idea behind `DisplayMember` is good, that is that you can choose which property will convey the identifier of an object. Too bad it has been implemented that way.

Comment: My point, specifically, was: why add null elements to an UI control as a ComboBox? What would the User pick from the list, an empty space? A placeholder like <Nothing here>, <#NaN>, <No Name>? If you need to just add *empty* strings to the list, then the suggestion to override ToString() is, IMO, the best/simplest thing you can do. If you really need to show those elements in a ComboBox, that is.

Comment: `Otherwise I should delcare an interface and implementi it both in Dog class and NullObject. Quite cumbersome for such a small task`  And yet, it's the proper solution to your issue.  I fail to understand the "cumbersome" part.

Comment: _Quite cumbersome for such a **small** task_ - based on the fact that you asked question here - it is not a small task at all ;)

Comment: No, I ask even questions that regard *details*. I think that in programming every detail counts.